10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Write at another/pleaseWork failed: Missing or insufficient permissions -> How do I fix this?
Making an app in SwiftUI for iOS. However, when I try to read or write to firebase firestore, I keep receiving an insufficient permissions error. When I try to search up solutions to this error, people are saying to check the rules, but my rules are very open and configured as such:
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}

Here is the code trying to write into Firestore:
class MapViewModel: ObservableObject {
  func fetchData() {
      let db = Firestore.firestore()
      db.document("another/pleaseWork").setData([
          "name": "Working Man",
          "age": 18,
      ])
  }
}

What is interesting is that I can read and write from Firebase firestore emulator, but I cannot do the same with my actual project. Since I am currently using Firebase auth emulator for authentification, is it possible that Firebase does not allow you to use the emulator for auth while also using the actual project for reading/writing to firestore, even though my rules are so open?
Here are the log errors:
[Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 10.28.1
This is the db:  <FIRFirestore: 0x600002138280>
10.28.1 - [GoogleUtilities/SceneDelegateSwizzler][I-SWZ001114] Successfully created Scene Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag GoogleUtilitiesAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO (Boolean) in the Info.plist
nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C1] Connection has no local endpoint
nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C1] Connection has no local endpoint
10.28.1 - [FirebaseSessions][I-SES000000] Data Collection is enabled for at least one Subscriber
10.28.1 - [FirebaseSessions][I-SES000000] [Settings] Cache is not expired, no fetch will be made.
10.28.1 - [FirebaseInstallations][I-FIS002001] -[FIRInstallationsIDController installationWithValidAuthTokenForcingRefresh:0], appName: __FIRAPP_DEFAULT
10.28.1 - [FirebaseInstallations][I-FIS002000] -[FIRInstallationsIDController createGetInstallationItemPromise], appName: __FIRAPP_DEFAULT
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Initializing. Current user: kTrNOa3nqjhiA6Lf4w4LyjHr6omk
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Using /Users/varunvaidya/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6D4B597E-A7E6-4367-9E33-851D1A9879AC/data/Containers/Data/Application/7FC17B4A-C5BE-4E38-971B-013D443B446D/Library/Application Support/firestore/__FIRAPP_DEFAULT/crowds-428014/main for LevelDB storage
10.28.1 - [FirebaseSessions][I-SES000000] Logging events using fast QOS due to running on a simulator
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Committing transaction: <LevelDbTransaction Start LevelDB: 0 changes (0 bytes):>
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Committing transaction: <LevelDbTransaction Start MutationQueue: 0 changes (0 bytes):>
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Committing transaction: <LevelDbTransaction Start IndexManager: 0 changes (0 bytes):>
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Committing transaction: <LevelDbTransaction migrate overlays: 0 changes (0 bytes):>
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Committing transaction: <LevelDbTransaction NextMutationBatchAfterBatchID: 0 changes (0 bytes):>
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Committing transaction: <LevelDbTransaction Locally write mutations: 7 changes (238 bytes):
  - Put [collection_parent: collection_id=another] (0 bytes)
  - Put [document_mutation: user_id=kTrNOa3nqjhiA6Lf4w4LyjHr6omk path=another/pleaseWork batch_id=1] (0 bytes)
  - Put [document_overlays: user_id=kTrNOa3nqjhiA6Lf4w4LyjHr6omk path=another/pleaseWork batch_id=1] (110 bytes)
  - Put [document_overlays_collection_group_index: user_id=kTrNOa3nqjhiA6Lf4w4LyjHr6omk collection_group=another batch_id=1 path=another/pleaseWork] (0 bytes)
  - Put [document_overlays_collection_index: user_id=kTrNOa3nqjhiA6Lf4w4LyjHr6omk path=another batch_id=1 document_id=pleaseWork] (0 bytes)
  - Put [document_overlays_largest_batch_id_index: user_id=kTrNOa3nqjhiA6Lf4w4LyjHr6omk batch_id=1 path=another/pleaseWork] (0 bytes)
  - Put [mutation: user_id=kTrNOa3nqjhiA6Lf4w4LyjHr6omk batch_id=1] (128 bytes)>
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Committing transaction: <LevelDbTransaction NotifyLocalViewChanges: 0 changes (0 bytes):>
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Committing transaction: <LevelDbTransaction NextMutationBatchAfterBatchID: 0 changes (0 bytes):>
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Committing transaction: <LevelDbTransaction NextMutationBatchAfterBatchID: 0 changes (0 bytes):>
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] (null)
10.28.1 - [FirebaseAuth][I-AUT000002] Token auto-refresh enabled.
10.28.1 - [FirebaseAuth][I-AUT000004] Token auto-refresh scheduled in 53:46 for the new token.
10.28.1 - [FirebaseAuth][I-AUT000017] Has valid access token. Estimated expiration date: 2024-07-10 11:16:47 +0000, current date: 2024-07-10 10:18:01 +0000
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Creating Firestore stub.
10.28.1 - [FirebaseSessions][I-SES000000] Successfully logged Session Start event to GoogleDataTransport
10.28.1 - [FirebaseSessions][I-SES000000] Successfully logged Session Start event
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] (null)
10.28.1 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] Settings downloaded successfully
nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C1] Connection has no local endpoint
nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C3] Connection has no local endpoint
nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C3] Connection has no local endpoint
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] (null)
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] (null)
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Committing transaction: <LevelDbTransaction Set stream token: 1 changes (11 bytes):
  - Put [mutation_queue: user_id=kTrNOa3nqjhiA6Lf4w4LyjHr6omk] (11 bytes)>
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] (null)
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] (null)
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] (null)
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] (null)
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] (null)
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] (null)
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] (null)
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] (null)
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] (null)
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Committing transaction: <LevelDbTransaction Reject batch: 7 changes (2 bytes):
  - Delete [document_mutation: user_id=kTrNOa3nqjhiA6Lf4w4LyjHr6omk path=another/pleaseWork batch_id=1]
  - Delete [document_overlays: user_id=kTrNOa3nqjhiA6Lf4w4LyjHr6omk path=another/pleaseWork batch_id=1]
  - Delete [document_overlays_collection_group_index: user_id=kTrNOa3nqjhiA6Lf4w4LyjHr6omk collection_group=another batch_id=1 path=another/pleaseWork]
  - Delete [document_overlays_collection_index: user_id=kTrNOa3nqjhiA6Lf4w4LyjHr6omk path=another batch_id=1 document_id=pleaseWork]
  - Delete [document_overlays_largest_batch_id_index: user_id=kTrNOa3nqjhiA6Lf4w4LyjHr6omk batch_id=1 path=another/pleaseWork]
  - Delete [mutation: user_id=kTrNOa3nqjhiA6Lf4w4LyjHr6omk batch_id=1]
  - Put [document_target: path=another/pleaseWork target_id=0] (2 bytes)>
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Write at another/pleaseWork failed: Missing or insufficient permissions.
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Committing transaction: <LevelDbTransaction NotifyLocalViewChanges: 0 changes (0 bytes):>
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Committing transaction: <LevelDbTransaction NextMutationBatchAfterBatchID: 0 changes (0 bytes):>
nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C3] Connection has no local endpoint
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Committing transaction: <LevelDbTransaction Backfill Indexes: 0 changes (0 bytes):>
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Garbage collection skipped; Cache size 7469 is lower than threshold 104857600
10.28.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Committing transaction: <LevelDbTransaction Collect garbage: 0 changes (0 bytes):>


Did you try to log the error if the setData operation fails?

Yes, I added the log errors from the setData operation. I am not sure what to do with it though, so I would appreciate it if you would take a look!

What is the line of code that throws Missing or insufficient permissions.?

the .setData method is the one that throws the "Write at another/pleaseWork failed: Missing or insufficient permissions" error

Please show us the rules.

Not sure what you mean. I included the rules in the initial posting (it is the first box of code). Appreciate the help!
